# Copying vector in itself

Tags: c++

I watched [this](https://youtu.be/2olsGf6JIkU?t=2264) talk(time stamp included). And here speaker says that to make this modification

> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} -> {1,2,3,**1,2,3,4,5**,9,10}

he used `std::copy` and it crashed, so you should use `std::copy_backward` instead.

But in my experience it's just vice versa.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/hDjMhubAg1vb1KZz

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.begin()+5, v.begin()+3);
    for(const auto& i : v)
        std::cout<<i<<','; 
}
```

This works just fine. And with `std::copy_backward` it's a crash.

Am I blind to something? Or is it the speaker mistaking?

Edit: My mistake was to assume both functions had same interpretation of arguments. With `std::copy_backward` I should've used `v.end()-2` instead of `v.begin()+3`.

Comment: `std::copty_backward` takes an iterator to the **last** element to copy to. So `v.begin()+8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it didn't crash means nothing. According to Standard, `std::copy` is undefined is if target iterator is within the range [first, last) - and this is your case. As we all know, not crashing is **just one** of the possible manifestations of undefined behavior.

In order to know why your `std::copy_backwards` crash, we need to see the code which uses it. I have a suspicion you used it incorrectly (it is **not** drop-in replacement for `std::copy`, you need to alter arguments accordingly).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is to the version which uses `std::copy`, which is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If the output iterator falls between the two input iterators, [behavior is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).  The fact that it worked for your example is a fluke.

With `std::copy_backward`, the third parameter is an iterator to the *last* output element.  So you have to change your example to:

```
std::copy_backward(v.begin(), v.begin()+5, v.begin()+8);
```